# C# Calling WCF behind DMZ

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, msmq, tunnel

I need to call a WCF service that is behind a DMZ:

```
WEBDMZ           ..    LANDMZ
-------------          ------------
ClientServer     =>    WCF service
```

As there is a firewall between the two it's not possible for the Client to connect to the WCF service. So I need the WCF service to connect to the client and "listen" to connections or create a tunnel somehow.

I feel it must be a very common problem but I haven't been able to find a proper solution yet. And no it's not possible to open a port. The connection have to be initiated by the WCF.

The client is a server and can easily host any MSMQ or other service.

It seems like this problem can also be referred to as "reverse proxy" or "reverse tunnel".

Solution ideas:

- MSMQ hosted by Client (but I'm afraid if it would just simply be polling all the time and creating a network overhead).
- A reverse tunnel/proxy?
- WCF Duplex?

I'm looking for the simplest solution, preferably in C# and without 3rd party software. Perhaps there is a WCF configuration that allows for reverse calls?

Comment: I have solved this problem using Azure Service Bus but that is a 3rd party tool. No need to open any ports, services are secured, there is a probability of protocol upgrade (aka direct connect).

Answer (score 1):

With .Net version 4, you can look at WCF Routing service at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee517423.aspx). Or you can build a routing service by yourself following example from Michele Leroux. Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc500646.aspx).

**EDIT:**

You can build a routing service, put it at WEBDMZ server, it will contains list of endpoint wcf service put at DMZ server. At here it will take role as a service server as well as client connect to services at DMZ server. You also can build a discovery service to configure these endpoints automatically.

Comment: You can build a routing service at WEBDMZ server which will contains list of endpoints wcf service at LANDMZ server. You also can apply discovery service to auto config these endpoints when a new wcf service has been launched. The routing service can apply polling or duplex service as well.